# Error #1006: removeChild is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm trying to create a game where in there's an object falling from the middle and you have to drag it in the left if it's good or right if it's bad.

What I'm having problems with right now is I don't know how the program would know if the object is good or bad. I think.

I'm getting an error:
Error #1006: removeChild is not a function.

I'm newbie at flash, if you have tips or whatever, please share!

http://pastebin.com/AnpN6tEy
    import flash.events.Event;

```
var tray:Array = new Array(Legal2_1,Legal2_2,Legal2_3,Legal2_4,Legal2_5,Legal2_6,Legal2_7,Legal2_8,Legal2_9,Legal2_10,Legal2_11,Legal2_12,Legal2_13,Legal2_14,Legal2_15,Illegal2_1,Illegal2_2,Illegal2_3,Illegal2_4,Illegal2_5,Illegal2_6,Illegal2_7,Illegal2_8,Illegal2_9,Illegal2_10,Illegal2_11,Illegal2_12,Illegal2_13,Illegal2_14,Illegal2_15);
var traypos:int;
var goodpos:int;
var badpos:int;

traypos = (stage.stageWidth / 2)-100;
goodpos = ((stage.stageWidth / 3) -100);
badpos = (((stage.stageWidth/3) *2) -100);

var timerT:Timer = new Timer(1000,120);
timerT.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, traytimerhandler);
timerT.start();

var secondsT:Number = 1;

function traytimerhandler(event:TimerEvent)
{
//trace("Seconds elapsed: " + seconds);
    SpawnTray(null);
    secondsT++;
}

function SpawnTray(event:Event):void
{
    var trayspawn:int;
    trayspawn = int(Math.random() * tray.length);

    var trayn:MovieClip = new tray[trayspawn]();

    addChild(trayn);

    trayn.x = traypos;
    trayn.y = -20;

    trayn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray(trayspawn));
    trayn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
//trayn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CheckTray(trayspawn));
}

function MoveTray(trayc:int):Function
{   
    return function(event:Event):void {
    var trayn:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
    trayn.y +=  5;
    if (trayn.y >= stage.stageHeight + 50)
    {
        CheckTray(trayc);
        trayn.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray);
        this.removeChild(trayn);
    }
    }
}

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray);
// surprise! This object will not be moved via MOUSE_DOWN,;
// because it's already being moved
    // e.target.addEventListener(
    e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
    e.target.startDrag();
}
// drag;


function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.stopDrag();
    e.target.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray);
    e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
    e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopDragging);
    return;// emergency exit. We don't need to do more
}

function CheckTray(trayspawn:int):Function
{   
    return function(event:Event):void {
    var trayn:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
    if (trayn.x <= goodpos)
    {
    //good side
        if (trayspawn<=14)
        {
            score +=  15;
        }
        else
        {
            score -=  15;
        }
    }
    if (trayn.x >= badpos)
    {
        //bad side
        if (trayspawn<=14)
        {
            score -=  15;
        }
        else
        {
            score +=  15;
        }
    }

    if (trayn.x > goodpos && trayn.x < badpos)
    {
        //middle
        score -=  15;

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit coercion error on line 37 is caused by the fact that `addEventListener` expects function. Change the line to:

```
trayn.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveTray);
```

"Undefined property event" problems have common cause. Event argument is missing in the signatures of the functions. They should be like this:

```
function MoveTray(event:Event):void

function CheckTray(event:Event):void
```

Comment: But I need to pass values in the functions.. I think. Unless there is other way.

Comment: What kind of values do you need to pass?

Comment: I've updated my code! I'm now having different error! Please check. Thank you and sorry!

Comment: Substitute this.removeChild with removeChild only. It looks like this is pointing to Timer instance.

Comment: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

Comment: This means you're trying to remove object from container to which it doesn't belong to.

Comment: So how would I remove the object in the MoveTray function?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the object that is dispatching the Event with the property target of the Event.

ex:

```
var m1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
m1.name = 'm1';
m1.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );

var m2:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
m2.name = 'm2';
m2.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    trace( 'onEnterFrame', e.target.name ); // you could see m1 and m2
}
```

Hope this could help you

Comment: Uhmmmm wouldn't that be trouble if let say I have 30 items? Is there an easier way? Could you check my code? I've edited it.